# a segment of the HTML code throwing an error

Tags: php, html

Keep getting an error at the third last line, with the div. What aren't i seeing?

```
<div id="PageContent">
  <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px"">
    <h2>Login to manage store</h2>


    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  </div>
 <?php 
 include_once("../template_footer.php");  ?>
</div>  //error
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `style` parameter is closed using two double quotes (`""`). It should not have anything to do with the error but should be fixed in any case.

Comment: HTML throwing an error? Very unlikley.. The worst error you'll get will be the HTML not displaying correctly

Comment: It just shows there was a syntax error, at the line stated.
I tried using single quotes to close, but it makes the rest of the code incorrect.
Daryl You're half right..cause it doesn't display at all

Answer (score 4):

You 'open' 2 divs and close them both before the "/div" that outputs the error. In other words, you are closing a div that you never opened :)

Comment: There is a div above the first. Sorry, didn't put that in

Comment: Edit the post by putting some more code so that we can see better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The last `</div>` is not closing any `<div>`. Besides, you have an extra `"` on your second `div`. Try this

```
<div id="PageContent">
  <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px">
    <h2>Login to manage store</h2>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  </div>
 <?php 
 include_once("../template_footer.php");  ?>
</body>
</html>
```